# The field <fieldname> does not exist in the database tableau error

Tags: mongodb, data-visualization, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I have created a tableau dashboard using MongoDB database.
We have 30 fields in the database.
I have created line graph which show average income of customer and it was working for the past 4 months but suddenly a week ago it stopped working and threw below error.
[Tableau error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnPR.png)

I have check the MongoDB collection and the field is there.
But when I see tableau extract it is not showing the field.
I want to find root cause of this and solution as well.

Comment: in that week ago, for any reason, did the field slightly changed name or type? is it a dimension or a measure?

Comment: @FabioFantoni no nothing changed

Comment: I bet you've already tried to replace/refresh the connection... and in addition to that, could you try to create a new workbook connected to the same source in order to see if that specific field appears or not in your dimension/measure list?

Comment: @FabioFantoni yes. Replaced with new connection, tried creating new workbook to see if I am getting all the fields but in new workbook the issue persist.

Comment: what's the type of that specific field out of curiosity?

Comment: @FabioFantoni it is float.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have checked the datasource and the filed does still exists I would try to open the workbook with Tableau Desktop, go to `Data` => `New Data Source` and make a brand new data source with the same structure of the one that shows you the error.

After that you can go to `Data` => `Replace Data Source` and change the source from the old to the new one.
Finally you have to close the old Data Source.

Please refer to these pages of the official Tableau Desktop guide:

- [Replace Data Sources](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_replace.htm)
- [Close Data Sources](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/close_connection.htm)

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is new data source also don't have that field.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import the data source again and then through data => replace data source and Tableau will automatically apply the sheets job again.